# SQL XPath with upper case INSERT fails with syntax error

Tags: xpath, sql-update, sql-server-2019

I have a SQL Server query to insert an XML node into some XML; when I use an upper case `INSERT` it gives a syntax error but lower case `insert` works.

```
UPDATE @xTABLE
SET x.modify('
INSERT <newthing>I am here</newthing>
as last
into (/rootthing/InsertInMe)[1]
');
```

**Why does this fail with a syntax error given the examples have upper case here:**

> Msg 2209, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
> XQuery [@xTABLE.x.modify()]: Syntax error near 'I'

Running this in SSMS.

As a reference this has upper case in the examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/insert-xml-dml?view=sql-server-ver15

Here is some sample SQL with the working (first one) and failing (second one) UPDATE:

```
-- setup some sample data:
DECLARE @xtable AS TABLE (
     x xml
);

DECLARE @x AS XML;
SET @x = '
<rootthing>
  <InsertInMe>
  </InsertInMe>
</rootthing>
';
INSERT INTO @xtable (x) Values(@x);

SELECT x AS xBefore
FROM @xtable;

-- this works
UPDATE @xTABLE
SET x.modify('
insert <newthing>I am here</newthing>
as last
into (/rootthing/InsertInMe)[1]
');

-- this gives a syntax error
UPDATE @xTABLE
SET x.modify('
INSERT <newthing>I am here</newthing>
as last
into (/rootthing/InsertInMe)[1]
');

SELECT x AS xAfter
FROM @xtable;
```

Comment: I added a reference for the base of my perplexed state.

Comment: [PR](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/pull/6824) sent for correction to documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XQuery is case sensitive. `INSERT` <> `insert`. This noted in XQuery's  [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xquery-20101214/) (which SQL Server follows per [XQuery Language Reference (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)) in section 2 "Basics".

> Like XML, XQuery is a case-sensitive language. Keywords in XQuery use lower-case characters and are not reserved—that is, names in XQuery expressions are allowed to be the same as language keywords, except for certain unprefixed function-names listed in A.3 Reserved Function Names.

As a result, `INSERT` is not a recognised syntax, as it's not `insert`.

Comment: So is the referenced page I added to my question from Microsoft for SQL Server just plain wrong?

Comment: Short answer, @MarkSchultheiss , yes. In long, see Section [5.1 Insert](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-30/#id-insert). I would (personally) raise an issue on the documentation's GitHub.